Counting total time, across a range of mixed shift patterns
I have an employee rota, which lists a range of employees and their shift patterns.
I need to know how many hours have been planned for the whole team, between set times per day.
i.e. across the various shift times, how many hours are planned between 22:00-00:00 (midnight) for Monday.
While some shifts might start and finish in that time frame, others will have stared before and finish after, e.g., 20:45-02:30
I tried this =COUNTIFS(C$10:C$50,"<="&$A57,D$10:D$50,">="&$B57)
Where Column C is the shift start times and D the finish times
and Columns A & B the Start and finish times that I need to know the planned hours between
which was a Good start, but only reads the number of cells with whole number, i.e., 20:00.
20:15 does not get picked up
it also only counts the number of cells which would be a number of employees, not the number of hours.

Please [edit] to include some sample table data and also an example of your desired results so I can better-understand what you expect.
